# Place pictures and ref it without using subcaption

Tags: floats, subfloats, subcaption, cleveref

I am writing a paper using [Springer LNCS](ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/llncs/llncs2e.zip) format, which is incompatible with the package `subcaption`. It provides `subfig` package instead.

I wish to achieve the following format (3-by-2, refer each one, and each column, actually the picture below does not truely reflect my expectation. I'm expecting left (a),(b),(c) Fig1, right (a),(b),(c) Fig2):

[image]

And I need refer each subcap using `\Cref{}` in the `cleveref` package.

With `subcaption` package, I can use the following code to achieve my goal. Can anyone tell me how to achieve the same goal without using `subcaption`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{subcaption,caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!hb]
\hspace*{-0.9in}
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{200pt}p{200pt}}
\includegraphics[width=200pt,height=80pt]{MyPic1.jpg} &
\includegraphics[width=200pt,height=80pt]{MyPic2.jpg}\\
\subcaption{\small{subcap 1}}\label{fig:subcap1}&
\subcaption{\small{subcap 2}}\label{fig:subcap2}\\
\includegraphics[width=200pt,height=80pt]{MyPic3.jpg} &
\includegraphics[width=200pt,height=80pt]{MyPic4.jpg}\\
\subcaption{\small{subcap 3}}\label{fig:subcap3}&
\subcaption{\small{subcap 4}}\label{fig:subcap4}\\
\includegraphics[width=200pt,height=80pt]{MyPic5.jpg}&
\includegraphics[width=200pt,height=80pt]{MyPic6.jpg}\\
\subcaption{\small{subcap 5}}\label{fig:subcap5}&
\subcaption{\small{subcap 6}}\label{fig:subcap6}\\
\caption{leftPics}\label{fig:left} &
\caption{rightPics}\label{fig:right}
\end{tabular}
\vspace{-0.1in}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you wether gave a picture nor a compileable code, its hard to tell, what you want to achive. However, does Springer support `subfigure`, which also supports subcaptions?

Comment: I download "llncs2e.zip" from this (http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs/lncs+authors?SGWID=0-40209-0-0-0) website. When I type `\usepakcage{subcaption}`, it shows `Package caption Error: The 'subcaption' package does not work correctly in compatibility mode.`

Answer (score 1):

So if I understood well your issue is that you have to use the `subfig` package instead of `subcaption`. Also you wanted a unique global caption instead of one caption per column, is that right?

Based on my understanding, here is the solution that I propose (I downloaded an image that I named `test.png` for the test purpose):

- use the `subfloat` command from the `subfig` package;
- don't forget to put one `caption` and one `label` per image, and another one for the global;
- load the `cleveref` package after all other packages (it is one of the few that must be loaded AFTER `hyperref`);
- the width that you force (200 pt) creates `overfull \hbox warning`s for me and makes you think that the image and the caption is not centered, so I used `\fbox` and another scale in the last images to show you that everything is well centered;
- if you want something else than centered, just replace the `\centering` command.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}                 % allowed
% \usepackage{subcaption,caption}   % not allowed
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!hb]
        \centering

        \subfloat[Caption 1\label{subfig1}]{\includegraphics[width=200pt,height=80pt]{test.png}}
        \subfloat[Caption 2\label{subfig2}]{\includegraphics[width=200pt,height=80pt]{test.png}}

        \subfloat[Caption 3\label{subfig3}]{\includegraphics[width=200pt,height=80pt]{test.png}}
        \subfloat[Caption 4\label{subfig4}]{\includegraphics[width=200pt,height=80pt]{test.png}}

        \subfloat[Caption 5\label{subfig5}]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=100pt]{test.png}}}
        \subfloat[Caption 6\label{subfig6}]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=100pt]{test.png}}}

        \caption{Global caption\label{globalfig}}
    \end{figure}

    This is a reference to \cref{subfig1} and this is a reference to \cref{globalfig}.

\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]